# Pixel & Percent in a HTML-Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a stats table for soccer(Football) games.

The table consists of the following columns (from left to right):

- icon
- text (what happend)
- minute
- text (what happend)
- icon

The icon & minute columns should have a static with (50px & 80px). The text columns should be variable in width.

Now to the tricky part... if the table has a text column with content and one without in the same row the minute column isn't centered anymore. See:

[image]

That's how it should look like:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<table class="table-comparison">
  <thead>
    <th colspan="5">
      Wechsel
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-action"><i class="icon-rotate-left"></i></td>
      <td class="column-text text-right">
        <i class="icon-caret-right color-green"></i> Sradan Lakic für <i class="icon-caret-right color-red-light"></i> Stefan Aigner
      </td>
      <td class="column-center" data-toggle="move:insertBefore" data-target="$el.parent().find('td:first-child')">46'</td>
      <td class="column-text">
        <div>
          <i class="icon-caret-right color-green"></i> Mario Götze für <i class="icon-caret-right color-red-light"></i> Toni Kroos
          </div>
          <div>
          <i class="icon-caret-right color-green"></i> Emre Can für <i class="icon-caret-right color-red-light"></i> Thiago Alcantara
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="column-action"><i class="icon-rotate-left"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-action"><i class="icon-rotate-left"></i></td>
      <td class="column-text text-right">
        <i class="icon-caret-right color-green"></i> Sebastion Jung für <i class="icon-caret-right color-red-light"></i> Marco Russ
      </td>
      <td class="column-center" data-toggle="move:insertBefore" data-target="$el.parent().find('td:first-child')">88'</td>
      <td class="column-text"></td>
      <td class="column-action"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the css:

```
// ------------------------------

.table-comparison {
  color: @black;
  width: 100%;

  th, td {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }

  th {
    .interstate;
    .uppercase;
    color: @black;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;

    @media @tablet {
      padding-bottom: 35px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }

  .column-action {
    padding-left: 20px; 
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;

    @media @phone {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  .column-text {
    padding-left: 20px; 
    padding-right: 20px;

    @media @phone {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .column-center {
    .interstate;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;

    @media @phone {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      padding-left: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }

    @media @tablet {
      border-left: 1px solid @grey-medium;
      border-right: 1px solid @grey-medium;
    }
  }

  // stripe that shit down
  // stripe down the tables
  > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td,
  > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > th {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
  }

  > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
  > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this give you what you want? jsfiddle.net/2dzDf/1/

Comment: @gvee yep, but I thought there might be a css-only solution.

Comment: First you say, "The text columns should be variable in width." and they you show that you want them to be fixed. So what should it be?

Comment: @AndreZimpel that is a CSS-only solution. All the JS does is show you the column widths. It doesn't modify them in any way.

Comment: @MrLister Where did I say that the text columns should be fixed? They should be variable in width.

Comment: @gvee my fault. sorry! but the problem is, that if there is no content in one of the cells (http://jsfiddle.net/2dzDf/3/) the minutes aren't centered anymore :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `table-layout:fixed;` that way, the column that did't get specific width, will 'divide' the rest of the width evenly between them.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/2dzDf/10/)

**CSS**

```
.table-comparison
{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.iconColumn
{
    width: 50px; /*fixed width*/
}
.textColumn
{
    /*you dont have to fix the width*/
}
.minuteColumn
{
    width: 80px; /*fixed width*/
}

/* this part is taken from gvee's solution*/
.table-comparison tr td:first-child, .table-comparison tr td:last-child {
    color: red;
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
}

.table-comparison tr td:nth-child(3) {

    background-color: lime;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table-comparison">
    <thead>
    <th class='iconColumn'></th>
    <th class='textColumn'></th>
    <th class='minuteColumn'></th>
    <th class='textColumn'></th>
    <th class='iconColumn'></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><i>i</i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>46'</td>
            <td>
                <div> <i>G</i>Mario Götze für<i>R</i>Toni Kroos</div>
                <div> <i>G</i> Emre Can für <i>R</i> Thiago Alcantara</div>
            </td>
            <td><i>i</i>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i>i</i> 
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>88'</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works just fine! Thank you very much! :)

(note: you have the th's outside of the thead)